# Putting components in a shield gives DRC errors in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I have multiple RF shields with footprints in Altium Designer.
When I put components in the shield in the PCB, I receive DRC errors of components collision. There might be some patch solutions like waiving the DRCs or etc., but I want to do it fundamentally. I also checked the Shield footprint and keep-out layer is empty. The courtyard and overlay layers are also empty.

[image: Components in the shield makes some violation as shown in the figure]

Comment: Can you add a picture of your errors on the PCB ?

Comment: Do your footprint(s) have 3D models?

Comment: This link will take you, with a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: [https://forum.live.altium.com/](https://forum.live.altium.com/)

Comment: @TimWilliams The components like capacitors and ICs have but the shield only has the pads without the component physical model.

Comment: @Bouboubi done. please check the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Tim is right, Altium as two ways to conclude if their is a collision. The first one is with 3D bodies. Most of the time, you should use it and all your components need to have a 3d body. If their is no 3d body, it will take all the component size and create an invisible box of the height inputted in the part description.

To place shields, you should create a 3d body if possible. If not, you can make an exception in the DRC for that component, but it is not advisable to do so since ou might actually collide.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available in the official documentation.

[Working with the Component Clearance Design Rule on a PCB in Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-placement-rule-component-clearance?version=21)

> When there are no 3D Body objects or closed contours on the Courtyard layer defined, the bounding rectangle formed by primitives on the silk, copper and mechanical layers (excluding .Designator and .Comment text strings) is used.

The shield collides with everything because, lacking a 3D model, it's assumed to occupy the entire vertical space within its outline.